# Windows cannot set folder security by user group

Tags: windows, active-directory, security, directory

I have create a new user group [**Group A**] in Windows Server, create a new user [**User 1**] as member of [**Group A**].

If I set a folder security to [**Allow**] by user [**User 1**], the setting will work, [**User 1**] can access the folder.

If I set the folder security to [**Allow**] by user group [**Group A**], the setting not work, [**User 1**] cannot access the folder even [**User 1**] is member of [**Group A**]

What I expect is I should able to set folder security by [**User Group**] instead of setting by [**User**]

Any steps I missing or wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The User must log off and log on again, otherwise the new group membership will not be effective.

Comment: or the user can run `klist purge` to delete existing Kerberos tickets. These get recreated when the user reauthenticates to stuff in the background - no logoff required.

Comment: @TrixM You can do that in a lab or for testing purposes but I wouldn't recommend doing that in production. Weird behavior can occur until you log off/on again, see the documentation.

Comment: Yes, I know. I have seen the doco, quite a lot in 20+ years.. But it's quick and easy and works nearly all the time. Definitely not a substitute for logging off regularly to keep things fresh, but for a quick check it's fine. Thus the comment and not a full answer. Also, it doesn't *hurt* anything in a production environment. If it doesn't seem to help, then the fallback is simply logging off/on again.

Comment: Thanks all for your advice. My mistake, I just **disconnect** rather than **sign out** from server. The folder security work after I sign out and sign in again.